# Json Object is giving OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: android, json

I'm using JSON Framework to update the data of client side from server. I have 30 Pojo Classes and i received the Http Response from server. I create the Object of Reader by using the method

```
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, "UNICODE");
```

And i pass it in the Json Object like this

```
synchronizationResponse = gson.fromJson(reader, SynchronizationResponse.class);
```

But this line is giving outOfMemory Exception.
I write the response in a file and found the size of file is around 12MB.
So is their any way to split the response in multiple response.So that i can read and write simultaneously to avoid OOM exception.

Looking for Help

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say, as long as we do not know, what your SynchronisationResponse Class looks like.
Whatever your content, if you can split it into sub-sections, do so and serialize those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) to parse a large stream of JSON without running out of memory.  The details are in the documentation, but basically you create a JsonReader:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, "UNICODE"));
```

and write a recursive descent parser using `reader.nextName()` to get keys, `reader.nextString()`, `reader.nextInt()`, etc. to get values, and `reader.beginObject()`, `reader.endObject()`, `reader.beginArray()`, `reader.endArray()` to mark object boundaries.

This allows you to read and process one piece at a time, at any granularity, without ever holding the entire structure in memory.  If the data is long-lived, you can store it in a database or a file.